# Finitely generated modules over non-commutative principal ideal rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

The structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain is well known. My question is about the noncommutative version of this theorem:

Let $R$ be a ring with identity without non-zero zero-divisors and such that every left ideal and every right ideal of $R$ is principal. An example of such a ring is a division ring $D$ or a polynomial ring $D[x]$ over the division ring $D$. If $M$ is a finitely generated module over $R$ is there a simple structure for $M$ as in the commutative case?

Comment: What ideals are principal: left, right, two-sided, all...?

Comment: the left and the right ideals are both principal.

Comment: I don't recall where (if) the proof breaks down. I think a proof in the noncommutative case might appear in P. M. Cohn's [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=YLnF1CE4xDUC&pg=PA77&dq=modules+over+a+principal+right+ideal+domain&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBWoVChMIzqzz5qWfyAIVSIYNCh0aQAHm#v=onepage&q=%22principal%20ideal%20domain%22&f=false) but I can't see the whole thing to verify. He is talking specifically about noncommutative PIDs.

Comment: Indeed, this is Theorem 1.4.10 in Cohn’s book (page 82).